# random line break

Tags: line-breaking

I have a question. LaTex does a random line break between`wenn` and  `\[ [x,y] \in I\]` in the penultimate line. Can someone tell me why and how I can fix it? Already tried \mbox{} and it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}       % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage[left=20mm, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%Kopf und Fußzeile
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{28.04.2020}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

%\clearscrheadfoot
%\ihead{hallo}
\title{}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\section{Ideale und Homomorphismen}
\subsection{Konstruktionen mit Hilfe von Idealen}

\textbf{Definition} Ein Unterraum $\mathit{I} $ einer Lie Algebra $\mathit{L} $ heißt \textit{Ideal} von $\mathit{L}$, wenn \[ [x,y] \in I\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's *nothing random* about TeX and LaTeX operations. The line break in question is, in fact, entirely deterministic: When LaTeX encounters `\[`, it must terminate the current line and switch to display-math mode. (The `\]` directive ends display-math mode.)

Comment: Also, do yourself a big favor and don't write `$\mathit{I} $` and `$\mathit{L} $`; instead, please write `$I$` and `$L$`.

Comment: @Mico what about `\pdfuniformdeviate` and `\pdfnormaldeviate`? (I know it's only pseudo random, just had to point to some randomness in TeX)

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz - Definitely just pseudorandom. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct `\[ <stuff> \]` starts displayed maths, so a formula that is to be displayed on its own line. That's why you get a line break after "wenn". If you don't want it, use inline maths, e.g., `\([x,y] \in I\)` or `$[x,y] \in I$`.

Comment: thank you, it works!